# How to assign a string to a row based on variables with numerical values in python

Tags: python, string, variables

I'm trying to produce a dataframe column with string entries, which will give a range of numbers, i.e. 'Age 12.5-25.6'. The lower and upper values are stored in variables, but I want to generate a string from them.

I've tried printing the required message and assigning the print command to a variable, but it doesn't seem to work:

just assigning some example values, but in fact these will be generated by the programme:

```
lowerBound=12.5
upperBound=25.6

range=print(lowerBound, '-', upperBound)

outputDF = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Age'])
```

I guess I have to make the column accept string values

```
outputDF['Age']=outputDF['Age'].astype(str)

outputDF.loc[0]=(range)
```

I wanted the result to be an entry in the first column of the dataframe to be 12.5-25.6, but it actually came out as 12.5, '-', 25.6 which doesn't look very good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> lowerBound = 12.5
>>> upperBound = 25.6
>>> range=print(lowerBound, '-', upperBound)
12.5 - 25.6 (is the output from the print statement)
>>> # The print statement assigns the value None to range
...
>>> print(range)
None
# To get the string you seem to want,
>>> range = str(lowerBound) + "-" + str(upperBound)
>>> print(range)
12.5-25.6
>>>
```